# Angularjs select default when loading remotely

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying to have a default value in a SELECT element using angular, and it doesn't seem to be working. No matter what I do, it always selects a blank default element, when the data is loaded remotely in the controller

Here's my HTML:

```
<select 
ng-options="Domain.Name for Domain in Domains"
ng-model="CurrentDomain"
ng-init="CurrentDomain = Domains[0]"
></select>
```

Here's the relevant controller code:

```
$scope.Domains = $resource('api/domain').query();
$scope.CurrentDomain = $scope.Domains[0];
```

I realize that this question has been asked many times, and I've read all other questions, but none of the suggestions seem to work. If anyone has any other suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is the promise return. you must assign the promise response to $scope.Domains and then assign Domains[0] to CurrentDomain

Comment: Shouldn't the angular templating library handle promises transparently? My understanding was that in the html the promise can be treated the same as the underlying object.

Comment: But the problem is the second statement. $scope.CurrentDomain = $scope.Domains[0]; From the code, I think $scope.Domains is undefined and $scope.Domains[0] will throw error;

Comment: Ah, okay, I added that afterwards based on some other stackoverflow answers. Ideally, I'd think ng-init="CurrentDomain = Domains[0]" should handle the default selection.

Comment: which version of angularjs you are using?

Comment: I'm using angular 1.2.20

Comment: Check this - http://plnkr.co/edit/ppjSWDKT4lHWvEcY0PMC?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the promise. `$scope.Domains` is promise and pending to resolve. So, `$scope.Domains[0]` is undefined at that point of time.

So, the correct code is as below

```
var Domains = $resource('api/domain').query(function(){
    $scope.Domains = Domains;
    $scope.CurrentDomain = Domains[0];
});
```

Plunkr version - http://plnkr.co/edit/ppjSWDKT4lHWvEcY0PMC?p=preview

Refer to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4298, `ng-init` is no longer able to resolve promise.

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I'm still curious why the ng-init by itself didn't work, but your answer did resolve my issue.

Comment: Welcome. :). The problem is ng-init evaluate the expression before $scope.Domains resolved. same issue like $scope.CurrentDomain = $scope.Domains[0];

Comment: @LamboJayapalan, I added explanation why ng-init not working in the answer. If earlier version of angularjs(*I not sure which), it should worked. It is recommended not to depends on directive to resolve promise

Comment: i'm sorry, but would that bind the select to `CurrentDomain` instead of binding it to `Domains` ?